# How to navigate different page after async method return response

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a screen App in which i have onGenerateRoute property of MaterialApp. In the routes method i make an api call and once i get the response i want to let user navigate to login screen

I tried calling my widget Login inside .then() function

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBlocProvider(
      child: LoginBlocProvider(
        child: MaterialApp(
          onGenerateRoute: routes,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Route routes(RouteSettings settings) {
    print(settings.name);
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          //HERE I AM MAKING API CALL
          final appBloc = AppBlocProvider.of(context);
          appBloc.verifyUser().then((response) {
            //HERE ONCE I GET THE RESPONSE I WANT TO NAVIGATE USER TO 
            //lOGIN ACTIVITY
            print('called');
            return Login();
          });
          return AppBlocProvider(
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        });
        break;
      case '/Login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Login();
        });
        break;
      case '/HomeScreen':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Home();
        });
        break;
    }
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      print('returned null');
    });
  }
```

api call get successful and even .then() method executes but login screen doesn't appear

Comment: Why can't you call Navigator.pushNamed() in that Future after the api call?

Comment: I tried even that but after that it's recursively getting called again and again  non stop and getting login page UI again and again on top of each other

Comment: If you need to start the app with an asynchronous call then you need to show the user that something is happening. You could, for example, for route '/' to make the call and then return a splash screen(instead of Login()). When the call returns then you use Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Login') to navigate to the actual login page.

Comment: I am showing circular progress indicator in the above example u can see. I will give it a try as u said. One question is there in the above code I also tried using Navigator.pushName(cxt,'/login') but since my login screen also has MaterialApp is that might be reason I am getting recursively call to future?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `return Login();` doesn't do anything was because another return has been executed already: `return AppBlocProvider(child: Widget());`

Similar to this sample, since a return has been already made, the other return won't do anything. The sample prints 'bar', and 'foo' was never printed using `print(bar());`.

```dart
void main() {
  print(bar());
}

Future<String> foo() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  return 'foo';
}

String bar(){
  String txt = 'bar';
  foo().then((String value){
    print('Future finished: $value');
    // Since print already got a String return,
    // returning this value won't do anything
    return value; // 'foo' won't be printed on main()
  });
  return txt;
}
```

You may want to consider moving the navigation inside Login and also display CircularProgressIndicator() there.